# Battlefield cant play Naval strike "YOU NEED TO DOWNLOAD AND INSTALL THIS EXPANSION."

Tags: battlefield-4

Today(31/3/2014) naval strike for battlefield 4 came out.
Origin said it had a new download available, and directly installed it(I have got premium).
There also was an update for battlelog(also installed that).
Now, when i am trying to join a game that has naval strike maps in it, it will give me an error saying:
REQUIRES ADDITIONAL EXPANSION PACK
BATTLEFIELD 4 - NAVAL STRIKE
YOU NEED TO DOWNLOAD AND INSTALL THIS EXPANSION.

I rebooted my computer twice, re logged in origin and battlelog, but i cant get it to work.
Also in my update folder in bf4 there is only Xpack0 and Xpack1.
I have searched on Google, and they say(for older expansion packs) that i need to go in regedit and add Installed with value true.
Tried Xpack2 and Xpack3 but that didn't help.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you tried a repair on the game within origin?  (right click on the game in origin and click repair)

Comment: Yes i have already tried that, i think that the problem is is that the expansion pack installed on D:/, and not on C:/ where BF4 in installed on. I later changed default storage for games to D:/ cause of a small ssd.

Comment: Also, there is a new plugin update for your web browser that was released today.  Have you installed that update?

Comment: That shouldnt cause a problem as I did the same.   What was the full registry path for that Xpack1 (etc) that you did?  I had to do that same thing to resolve that issue.

Comment: I have the same problem did anyone solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to reinstall the game, or update the registry key to show that you have the expansion installed.

http://www.reddit.com/r/battlefield_4/comments/1tbt2p/solution_for_missing_china_rising_expansion_error/

> Back up your registry
>
> Log out and fully exit Origin
>
> Open your Registry Editor - Type in regedit in the Search Menu and press Enter
>
> Navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SOFTWARE > Wow6432Node > EA Games > Battlefield 4
>
> Check for a folder named Xpack1 under the Battlefield 4 folder
>
> If it exists -> Click on Xpack1, on the right pane see if there is a string named
>
> Installed. Double click on Installed string and set the Value data to True
>
> If it does not exists -> Right-click on Battlefield 4 select New then select Key a new folder will be created, name it Xpack1 right-click on Xpack1 > New > String Value > name this string Installed on the right-pane, double-click on Installed, set Value Data to True
>
> 5 . Exit Registry Editor
>
> Once all these steps have been completed, log in to Origin and start up Battlefield 4 and join China Rising Maps
>
> I got this help from EA online assist.

Comment: I think that the problem is is that the expansion pack installed on D:/, and not on C:/ where BF4 in installed on. I later changed default storage for games to D:/ cause of a small ssd. I reinstalled everything, and it works now!

Comment: This worked for me but you also have to do it for Xpack2.

Comment: http://answers.ea.com/t5/Battlefield-4/BF4-PC-China-Rising-DLC-Problem/m-p/2017595#U2017595   Xpack0 = Second Assault
Xpack1 = China Rising
Xpack2 = Naval Strike